# EF4 - is it possible for non-POCO entities to implement an interface?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Just wondering, is it possible for entities created via model/DB first to implement an interface?  If so, would it just take adding it to a partial class, like so:

```
public partial class SomeEntity : ISomeInterface
{
    // blah
}
```

Or would it be more involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the approach you suggested should work normally.  Alternatively you can use custom T4 templates to generate your classes with the interface implementations already present (via the template).